# Bluetooth microphone - can an external adapter improve things?

Tags: sound, bluetooth, microphone, 20.10

As far as I'm aware, no bluetooth microphone (in a microphone headset) ever works well with Ubuntu. I've tried several and many in my team have also tried several.

The microphone is usually disabled by default, using the laptop microphone instead. You can manually switch the audio type to enable the microphone, but then the audio sounds awful, like unusably bad. So most people I know of simply use a Bluetooth headset with the laptop microphone.

I'm wondering if anyone knows of an external Bluetooth adapter which could appear to the system as something else, that might do a better job of supporting a Bluetooth microphone?

Comment: I'm buying https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B07W6ZNMGN/ to see if it solves my problem. I'll update here if it does.

Comment: Hmmm... Bluetooth is a pain the Linux it seems. I don't use it but here's an interesting read: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxhardware/comments/67vjax/looking_for_a_headset_that_works_at_least_on/

Comment: It will not matter what Bluetooth adapter you use. The Bluetooth profile you choose will either give you sound and mic poor sound I agree or sound only good sound.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm reading, but it seems to me that microphone headsets sound vastly superior, when in 2way mode, on Android or iPhone etc than on Ubuntu. Why is that? Is it because they're using proprietary tricks that are unavailable to ubuntu?